# localhost cant connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: localhost, hadoop

i have some java systems that i want to use hadoop in with it, but whenever i connect to localhost with this command

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

it will always prompt that

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: local.localdomain: diginiqlinux.localdomain
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1466)
```

**edit**

here is my //etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

full trace log

```
[root@diginiqlinux ~]# hadoop fs -ls
13/12/30 16:44:36 INFO metrics.MetricsUtil: Unable to obtain hostName
java.net.UnknownHostException: diginiqlinux.localdomain: diginiqlinux.localdomai                                                                                        n
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1466)
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics.MetricsUtil.getHostName(MetricsUtil.java:91                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.hadoop.metrics.MetricsUtil.createRecord(MetricsUtil.java:8                                                                                        0)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.<init>(Use                                                                                        rGroupInformation.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInf                                                                                        ormation.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1757                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1750                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1618)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.init(FsShell.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:1813)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:1974)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: diginiqlinux.localdomain
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:894)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:128                                                                                        6)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1462)
        ... 14 more
ls: Cannot access .: No such file or directory.
```

any solution how to connect localhost?

Comment: You are probably not able to 'ping localhost' either. Post the output of the 'ping localhost' command if possible.

Comment: @Jay i can ping to localhost and 127.0.0.1

Comment: The second line in your /etc/hosts is invalid; remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add entry 127.0.0.1 for localhost in `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: thank u for your answer , it already has, but still cant do it

Comment: i can ping localhost

Comment: i will give u a screenshot

Comment: http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/7403/f243.jpg

Comment: i have updated the question , now it has a full log

Comment: Can you explain the hadoop command and its options? Did you notice the error related to ls at the end?

Comment: this command is just for list the Shared file on HDFS, like ls in linux , thanks jay, after i notice it, its not a problem, 

i add this hadoop fs -mkdir y
and when i list it hadoop fs -ls

i see my directory there 

root supergroup          0 2013-12-30 16:59 /user/root/x


but i still wondering why that error can be happen?

Comment: Is the error gone now?

Comment: no, error is still exists , error log still exists , but i dont know why it's not affect the systems, it connect, i can ignore the error,

Comment: after i discovered , i found that . yeah just like u said //etc/hosts is wrong it wrote myip root@localdomain after i comment it, it works like a charm haha thank u

Answer (score 1):

In the /etc/hosts file, there may be a `127.0.1.1 [hostname]` line. I would change that to `127.0.0.1 [hostname]`. I believe it is needed in order for sudo to work properly and there is generally an issue with it. 
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
The core-site.xml could also use `localhost` or the `hostname`, make sure it's configured properly.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://[hostname]:9000</value>
</property>
```